# Converting special characters into HTML entities, why or why not?

Tags: php, html, utf-8, escaping

I was wondering, what is the best practice. To convert all utf-8 special characters into HTML entities or only to escape &, < and >.

I'm working on several PHP projects. And google is displaying some wrong utf-8 results for a random part of my website.

I think this is because of one or both of the two following reasons:

- My hosting provider didn't automatically send the encoding headers (I already fixed this).
- Or the fact that in the description the text was not fully escaped.

Besides that, I noticed that most of the mayor company websites don't send the `'<?xml version'`  line and they don't escape their characters.

Are there downsides (or upsides) to escaping all characters vs only the minimum necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there downsides (or upsides) to escaping all characters vs only the minimum necessary?

Converting any characters beyond `<>&"'` (as done by [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)) is not necessary nowadays. If the page's character set is properly configured, it is no problem to use native UTF-8 characters (or whichever character set you choose). Converting them into entities has no advantage. They are sometimes used as a misguided workaround to character set issues, but this is almost never a good idea.

Comment: You say htmlentities, however you link to htmlspecialchars. But I understand your point. And what about the '<?xml' header, any advise about that one?

Comment: @Paul fixed, thanks! Re the XML header, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that, in what context are you expecting that to be sent?

Comment: The first line of the html document, w3 says to use `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` however mayor sites don't use  this line.

Comment: @Paul that's an *XML* prolog, it has nothing to do with [HTML.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)